# Can't import nltk module in Juypter notebook?

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter-notebook

I have tried importing nltk module using notebook (Juypter) but its keep showing the error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b06499430ee0> in <module>()
----> 1 import nltk

ImportError: No module named nltk.
```

I have looked at the various solutions. I am able to import the module with the terminal but not in the notebook.

Comment: Your terminal Python installation and your ipython install are separate. What does `import sys; print(sys.path)` produce in either? Or `sys.executable` for that matter.

Comment: Could you import in another environment? e.g. ipython, python shell?

Comment: @JimRaynor: Yes I am able to import in the python shell and even ipython while using bash.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is the output  :['',   '/Users/farihanaz/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/farihanaz/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py2.7.egg', '/Users/farihanaz/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/farihanaz/.ipython']

Comment: Anaconda comes bundled with the nltk. Are you sure it's succeeding on the commandline and failing in the Notebook, **and not the other way around?** Check if `/Users/farihanaz/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk` exists. If not, find out where it is (ask the successful python for `nltk.__file__`).

Comment: @alexis: Yes on the command line its working and even nltk folder is there in the site-packages folder.

Comment: as @MartijnPieters suggested ------ import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy --------- will work

Answer (score 12):

Open a command prompt and write:

```
pip install nltk
```

This will install the natural language toolkit, after the installation is complete, open Jupyter Notebook and type:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

It will take some time and after some time for the auto-configuration of the Jupyter Notebook. Later, you would be able to use is without any issues. Let me know, if you still face any problem.

Comment: I didn't use `nltk.download()`, but I was able to import `sent_tokenize, word_tokenize`

Answer (score 0):

If you have anaconda distribution already installed, nltk comes with it by default.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I downloaded all the packages in `nltk`. It worked

I didn't use `nltk.download()` however it is showing error at SentimentIntensityAnalyzer.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.sentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm sia = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()'
```

Here's is image for reference:
[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAcPm.png)